# JavaFX java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: javafx

Help! I'm stuck.. I try to run my main javafx app

Here is my codes;

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/utmkl/fxml/SimulatorDisplay.fxml"));
        Parent content = (Parent)loader.load(); 

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(content));
    primaryStage.show();            
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Below is my folder structure:
picture [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVQ37.png)

Below is the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at com.utmkl.VMCSManager.start(VMCSManager.java:43)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the answer..

the resource need to be in the same folder structure as main class

Here is my **Maven-JavaFX Folder structure**

```
VMCS
- src/main/java
     - com.utmkl
          VMCSManager.java
- src/main/resources
     - com.utmkl.fxml
          SimulatorDisplay.fxml
```

So, the correct code (which success to run)

VMCSManager.java

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("fxml/SimulatorDisplay.fxml"));
            Parent content = loader.load(); 

            Scene scene = new Scene(content);

            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had to change `fxml/nameofview.fmxl` to `/fxml/nameofview.fxml` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you do set a location with `loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/utmkl/fxml/ControllerDisplay.fxml"));` it is likely that the resource URL doesn't actually refer to an existing resource on the classpath.

If you add `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/com/utmkl/fxml/ControllerDisplay.fxml"));` to your code I think it will print `null` as a result.

Comment: I think it's something to do with maven project structure.. I just don't know how to resolve this at the moment

Comment: I don't use Maven but Gradle, but afaik Gradle's default directory structure is the same as Maven's. In src/main/java you should have your Java source, in src/main/resources your resources such as your FXML. If you build your app Maven will combine them. 

In IDEs such as Eclipse you will need to make sure both directories are marked as source folders, otherwise if you run your application from within your IDE it will not add the resources to the classpath. 

With Gradle's plugin this is done automatically when importing the Gradle project. I suspect something exists for Maven too.