# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set - at startup

Tags: java, javafx

I want to run my application, but an exception returns to me. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721851/javafx-java-lang-illegalstateexception-location-is-not-set) and did it the same way, but it did not help me. I think the mistake is stupid, but I don't see it, and I don't understand what to do, please help.

my main method

```
public class App extends Application {
    private Stage menuBar;
    private BorderPane mainWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.menuBar = primaryStage;

        initMenuWindow();
    }

    private void initMenuWindow() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("menuWindow.fxml"));
            mainWindow = loader.load();     //ERROR

            Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow);
            menuBar.setScene(scene);

            menuBar.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and exception

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at java/zherikhov.App.initMenuWindow(App.java:48)
    at java/zherikhov.App.start(App.java:27)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application zherikhov.App
```

my java module

```
module java {
    opens zherikhov to javafx.fxml;
    exports zherikhov;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
}
```

[[image: screenshot]
[[image: screenshot]

Comment: My guess is the path to the fxml file in `loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("menuWindow.fxml"));`. Try `"/menuWindow.fxml"` and other options... See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228487/javafx-location-is-not-set-error-message).

Comment: @deHaar `/menuWindow.fxml` is probably the first thing I tried) and I also experimented with the paths, but I agree, I think the problem is somewhere here

Comment: This has been asked and answered dozens of times. Please try the search feature and search for "Location not set."

Comment: What is the command you use to execute your application?

Comment: `/menuWindow.fxml` seems the incorrect path. Paths relative to the class seemed to stop working at some time for my IDE/JDK, but the complete path continues to work. Have you tried `/zherikhov/menuWindow.fxml`?

Comment: @fabian yes i tried

Comment: @Slaw If I understand you correctly, then I work at `IntelliJ IDEA` and use the `Run App` to run.

Comment: Can you check your `target/classes` directory to see if the resources are being copied to the output?

Comment: @Slaw it turns out no, I attached a screenshot

Comment: Then that's the source of the problem. Unfortunately, as you're using the IDE directly to build and run your project (rather than delegating to Maven), I'm not sure how to fix it. I would have assumed the problem was caused by IntelliJ not recognizing the `src/main/resources` directory as a resources root, but the directory's icon would indicate otherwise (you may want to still check this to be sure). If you run `mvn compile` are the resources copied?

Comment: try `/zherikhov/menuwindow.fxml` , it should work (most probably, 'cause of the location of the fxml)

Comment: @Ryotsu I tried, in fact, I think the problem is somewhere else, I just don't have enough experience to pay attention to it

Comment: @VladZherihov yeah, I tired your code too with your directory structure and it seems to be working well but I used Java 8, seems like the fxml's are missing in your maven generated output

Comment: @Ryotsu I don't know what the reason was, but I just re-created the project and it all worked

Comment: @Slaw I don't know what the reason was, but I just re-created the project and it all worked

Answer (score -1):

Your problem looks simple,
Just replace the FXML file name `menuWindow.fxml` with the full path of the file starting at the **src** file, ending with the filename with the `.fxml`

*I hope this works for you ( it worked in my case but your project's structure looks different)*

Comment: I've probably tried all the different options for the paths, otherwise I would not have come here.